# Take the group average

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've two columns: A and B; for each 3 rows in A column, I want to take the average of that 3 rows and write to B. here is the example:

```
A  B
10 20
20 50
30
40
50
60
```

I need the excel formula of this calculation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data in column `A` are in range `A1:A100`, then use following formula, say in `B1`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($A$1:$A$100,3*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))+1):INDEX($A$1:$A$100,3*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1)))
```

and drag it down

Comment: yeap, sorry for columns name; I changed.

Comment: yes, gives an error, says "not trying to write a formula?"

Comment: try to change commas `,` to semicolons `;` like this: `=AVERAGE(INDEX($A$1:$A$100;3*(ROW()-ROW($B$1))+1):INDEX($A$1:$A$100;3*(ROW()-ROW($B$1)+1)))`

Comment: now all cells are #NAME?. I tried both in B and C columns' first cell

Comment: what is the language of your excel?

Comment: ok, just copy formula from this test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycijqiu8gx8ycf9/test_average.xlsx

Comment: @simoco, interesting formula. Can you please explain what `Row($B$1)` is doing here. My question is, if this is always referring to `$B$1`, why can't we use constant 1 instead ?

Comment: @sudhi, you're right, if we use formula in any cell of _first row_, we can change `Row($B$1)` to `1`. However, as I mentioned in my answer `then use following formula, say in B1` - it's just a assumption. If OP desided to use this formula, say, in `D53`, they should change `Row($B$1)` to `Row($D$53)` (or `Row($B$53)`, or just `53` - it doesn't matter) - otherwise formula won't work..:) I decided to use `Row($B$1)` instead `1` to emphasize that formula depends on cell where it's placed